# Wordpress suddenly displaying home page on all permalink URLs

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My Wordpress is suddenly displaying the homepage instead of any posts.

All Page and category URLs work fine, it's just Posts.

It's not a permalink issue as it happens using default urls (eg: ?p=123)

Ive been using W3 Total Cache, but turned that off for now. Problem remains.

All Plugins are upto date. I've tried deactivating them all, tried running each one seperately, no change.

Using Wordpress 3.(something), it's the latest anyway, I always update the second I see the notice.

Theme is custom, but as I said, it work fine until a few hours ago.

URL: http://www.yorkcityknights.co.uk

Comment: I can't find a problem. Please provide some of the problem URLs. BTW, that's my home team!

Comment: Looks to be working fine to me.

Comment: Yeah sorry, found the problem, see edit above. Feel free to send me a slap by telekenesis, I'll happily accept it. Thanks for taking a look anyway

Comment: @Beliskner - Spookily small world. Feel free to get in touch, you'll find me on there easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

MyShadowSelf noticed he'd accidentally deleted single.php from his theme.